# compiling c and c++ code together as one .exe file in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to port a piece of software from Linux to Windows. Actual software is written primarily in C++ and significant code is in C language. I tried to compile this code using Visual Studio 2012 (because I am using windows 2007) but at linking time I am getting many errors which says the function calls in C files are unknown entries. This software compiles, links and run fine on Linux so there are no issues with include of  or anything silly like that.

Has anyone run into this issue? Does anyone know how to resolve it?

Please note that I have to do a native port so cygwin or other mingw are not options for me.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Is all of the code in a single Visual Studio project?

Comment: have you tried compiling C code as C++?

Comment: Search the web for "name mangling".  The C++ compiler changes the names of the C++ functions.

Comment: Is it a *compiler* error (not declared) or a *linker* error (not being linked in). (In other words, show the *exact* error message)

Comment: What is the invocation, on Linux, for the compilation and linking?

Comment: Yes all of the code is in a single Visual Studio project.  It is a linker error. I will do some research for "name mangling". Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, you are using some kind of Linux-specific library. The most obvious example would be unistd.h, which doesn't really have a direct equivalent in Windows.

Comment: I have replaced all the linux specific calls to windows so that should not  be a stopping point. I am getting linking time error so I would think that it is fine with all function calls.